# jQuery onclick all images in body

Tags: jquery, onclick, document, image

English isnt my native language so bear with me.

Im trying to make it so that when a user clicks any image on my site a gallery sort of div will become visible containing the image at its fullest size.

The way I've done now is;

```
    var image = $("body > image");


image.on('click', function(){
    var imageURL = $(this).attr('src');
    backgroundCurtain.css({"display": "block"});
    imageResized.attr("src", imageURL);
    var imageWidth = imageResized.width();
    pictureInner.css({"width" : imageWidth});
});
```

This isn't working and to be honest I wasn't expecting it to work. How do I call it so that every image element inside body. How do I "call" every image inside body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reference all images using jquery, simply do

```
var images = $("img");
```

Usually you don't want to have this to apply to all images, though (for example the imageResized shouldn't be in this set). A good solution is to add a css class (for example `class="zoomable"`) to the elements you want to be zoomable and use this selector :

```
var images = $("img.zoomable");
```

Have a look at [this reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Note that most of the time, we don't use the same URL for the bigger image as this would mean to have big images loaded for thumbnails. My practice is to have a naming pattern like "someFile.jpg" and "someFile-big.jpg" and to do this kind of thing :

```
$("img.zoomable").on('click', function(){
    var imageURL = $(this).attr('src');
    backgroundCurtain.css({"display": "block"});
    imageResized.onload = function(){
        var imageWidth = imageResized.width();
        pictureInner.css({"width" : imageWidth});
    };
    imageResized.attr("src", imageURL.split('.')[0]+'-big.jpg');
});
```

Comment: @Will Note that `$("body > img")` will only catch `<img/>` which are direct children (because of `>`)

Comment: What do you mean with "non defined imageResized var"? Where? The "var imageWidth = imageResized.width();" ?

Comment: @WillB I was wondering if your imageResized variable was defined. I guess it probably is.

Comment: @samsamX You're totally right. I suppose `$('img.someClass')` is what is needed by OP.

Comment: @dystroy The website im working on is http://ngmat.site90.net/webbdesign/william.html. Which approach do you think would be best, is the one I'm using now suitable for what I want to do in your opinion?

Comment: I can't help you on the whole web design (it's nice). The approach I suggest would perfectly fit but I don't get why you want to have those two images magnifiable.

Comment: @dystroy I was meaning the specific jQuery code I posted and its function :). The website is just an exercise for web design so I just wanna put as much as possible into it. Thanks for your help anyway, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
var image = $("img");

image.on('click', function(){
    var imageURL = this.src;
    backgroundCurtain.css("display", "block");
    imageResized.attr("src", imageURL);
    var imageWidth = imageResized.width();
    pictureInner.css("width", imageWidth);
}); ​
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your selector. The '>' selector specifies an immediate child `<body><img /></body>`. The selector that @dstroy is suggesting would simply grab any image on the entire page. This, though, may not be what your are trying to accomplish.

I'm assuming you have some form element (let's assume a DIV with ID 'gallery') that contains all of the images you are interested in. You could then use

```
var images = $("#gallery img");
```

This way, icons and 'chrome' images won't be displayed on the background.